# Cordova splash screen remove

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen, phonegap-build

Is it possible to disable Cordova default splash screen? I have removed the plugin but the default splash screen for iPhone still is showing and for Android the white screen is showing. Can this be fully removed?

Comment: Can you try `navigator.splashscreen.hide()` on deviceReady and tell what happens?

Comment: I have added the code but nothign happnes it's the same splash screen is howing again (.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  //navigator.splashscreen.hide();
 }, 5000))

Comment: Inside the ready function, you just need to add `navigator.splashscreen.hide();`. Adding that timeout means you are telling it to be visible for 5 seconds and then hide.

Comment: Have tried but it's the same as previous splash screen is still showing.(.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 navigator.splashscreen.hide();)

Comment: I do not have experience with iOS, but there are ways to make it work with native code. As for Android, maybe the blank white screen you see is due to the time taken to load your application in phone's main memory?

Comment: The white flash is probably caused by not setting the splash icon correctly: `<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />` with a screen.png file mentioned somewhere

Answer (score 91, accepted):

in your `config.xml` change the value to none in the below line

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

Comment: This did not work for me:

    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>

I followed this up with:
`ionic platform remove ios` 
`ionic platform add ios` 
`ionic build ios`

But when running from the xcode, I still have the splash screen.

Comment: I haven't tested this on ios, but it worked well for android build.

Comment: @Viky293 it's not working for me.. can you please help?

Comment: @VishalVyas provide me some more details, are you doing this for android?

Comment: @Viky293 check my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983340/ionic-ios-remove-default-splash-screen

Comment: @BillButler to disable the Splash Screen on iOS use `<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>`

Comment: It didn't work for me. Tried changing config.xml as suggested, but nothing. The splash screen is not displayed, but I have a white screen for 4-5 seconds instead. Can I get rid of EVERYTHING and just start the app immediately? thanks

Comment: 2019: This is not working, to fix see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936535/984471

Comment: Just in case, file location: android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml

Comment: For ios it's working but for android 12 its not working

Answer (score 11):

You can try the command to remove cordova splash screen

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Comment: Is it possible to run this on build.phonegap.com?

Comment: You can use the command as explained here http://docs.phonegap.com/references/phonegap-cli/cordova/. For the above command just write `phonegap cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen`

Comment: I have tried this, but still show the splash screen in IOS!

Comment: are you using phonegap or cordova ??

Answer (score 5):

```
cordova plugin -rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Comment: I guess it should be `rm`, not `-rm`

Answer (score 5):

Tested on android:

**To temporarily remove delay caused by splash screen:**

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
```

**To permanently remove splash screen:**

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Below did not work:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
```

You can add this to the `intelxdk.config.additions.xml`file.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely remove splash screen from your project

`cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen`

Answer (score -3):

Hi if nothing is working..
for android Goto android build folder find this com\getcapacitor\Splash.java inside capacitor-android project and comment this two line....

line number near by 196
show(a, DEFAULT_LAUNCH_SHOW_DURATION, DEFAULT_FADE_IN_DURATION, DEFAULT_FADE_OUT_DURATION, DEFAULT_AUTO_HIDE, null, null);

line number near by 189
show(a, duration, 0, DEFAULT_FADE_OUT_DURATION, autohide, null, true, config);
here you can also set false to 7th parameter - show(a, duration, 0, DEFAULT_FADE_OUT_DURATION, autohide, null, false, config); but it will show you some blank image on startup..so it is good to comment both function....still it is loading white screen at startup..i am finding this issue and soon solve....... then i will update here..

and donot forget to set config.xml setting as told above...