# Ionic iOS remove default splash screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685683/801437)

BUT didn't work

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

After this I also tried

```
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios
ionic emulate ios
```

But it didn't work

**Other details:**

```
vishal$ ionic -version
1.7.10

vishal$ cordova -version
5.4.0

vishal$ npm -version
2.14.7
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.splashscreenapp489828" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>splashscreenApp</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="ios">
    ...
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Please help :(

**Edit:**

Tried `vishal$ cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-splashscreen` 
But no luck :(

Plugin list:

```
vishal$ cordova plugin list
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.5 "Keyboard"
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.5.0 "PushPlugin"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2-dev "Console"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.2-dev "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.2.0 "Toast"
io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite 0.7.10 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
```

Comment: ios will always show a launch image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splash screen is provided by `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`. Try removing the plugin

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Or refer to the docs on the plugin project for showing and hiding the splash screen [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen).

Comment: Tried this already... no luck :( Still the default robot splash screen is visible!

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean. IOS requires a splash screen. This is something that is displayed before your app is fully running. You have the option of managing the properties of the splash screen via the Cordova splash screen plugin. When this plugin is removed you are seeing a default IOS splash screen which is the robot when using the emulator. The robot splash screen is not coming from Ionic.