# How to disable the splash screen on iOS with Cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I would like to not have a splash screen for an app I am developing for Android and iOS using Cordova. The [documentation for the plugin cordova-plugin-splashscreen](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/) explains how to do it but it works for Android and not iOS:
[image]
[image]

I have tried the suggestions [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472150/cordova-splash-screen-remove) and they too don't work.

Has anyone successfully disabled the splash screen on iOS with Cordova and, if so, how was it done?

Comment: Facing the same issue it's not working for iOS and windows for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS there is a thing called launch images (or launch storyboard) and you can't get rid of it, neither control it. The splash screen plugin just mimic it so you can "extend" the time of the launch image, when the launch image disappears the splash screen appears with the same image.

Removing the plugin or adding it and setting delay and duration to 0 just removes the splash image, but not the launch image, it can't be avoided.

Comment: Interesting. With Cordova where does iOS get the images for the launch images?

Comment: The launch images are also configured with the splash tags as for the splash images, as I said, the splash screen plugin shows the same image again when the launch images disappears.